# Complexity classes for BSS machines

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory, computer-science

Given a first-order structure $\mathcal{S}$, a *Blum-Shub-Smale machine on $\mathcal{S}$* is essentially a Turing machine where

- Cells on the tape can hold arbitrary elements of $\mathcal{S}$.
- The functions and relations in the language of $\mathcal{S}$, as well as equality, are "atomic" operations which can be performed on cells or checked whether they hold of cells.

See e.g. http://www.emis.de/journals/BBMS/Bulletin/bul971/meer.pdf for a formal description. (Note that BSS machines are usually defined just for rings or ordered rings, but there's no cost to the additional generality.) If $\mathcal{S}$ happens to be the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, then this is just the usual definition of Turing machine (with the notion of "input" tweaked appropriately).

Now, given a classical complexity class $\mathfrak{C}$, we can ask about the BSS-analogue of $\mathfrak{C}$ over different structures; for instance, whether $P=NP$ is true over different structures. (Note that of course, we aren't guaranteed to get something interesting out of this analogizing, but it is something we can do.) My question is about the other direction: are there reasonably natural complexity classes, which aren't obviously meaningful in the classical case, which are useful for BSS machines over different structures?

For example, let's look at BSS machines over a ring $R$ with a distinguished subring $S$ - for instance, take $R=\mathbb{R}$, and $S=\mathbb{Q}$. For a given run of a BSS machine $\pi$, let the *use set* of $\pi$, $u(\pi)$, be the set of elements of $R$ which every appear on the tape during the run $\pi$. Now, I want to measure how algebraically complicated this set is. One way to do this is to ask, "What is the dimension of the smallest sub-$S$-module of $R$ containing $u(\pi)$?" Call this the *dimension* of $\pi$. This number, $d(\pi)$, then forms a resource which - like time or space in the classical cases - we can restrict. So, for instance, we could look at the set of subsets of $R$ which are decidable by BSS machines with - for some fixed $n$ - $d(\pi)<n$ for all runs $\pi$. (This is roughly counting the number of times you *really* need to multiply, although I wouldn't push this intuition too far.)

Now, granted, as far as I can tell **this would be silly**, but this is the sort of thing I'm asking about: a kind of complexity class which is reasonably natural (OK, maybe that one's not natural, but it's not too *un*natural) and which are fundamentally not analogues of any classical complexity class.

Are there any examples of this sort of thing known?

Comment: This is an interesting question but there seems to be an upper bound on how natural such a class can be, because it seems that it must become trivial when you specialize to $\cal S = \mathbb{Z}/\mathrm{2}\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @TimothyChow Yes, such a class would only be interesting over structures other than $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But I don't think that's necessarily a problem - other structures *are* interesting. Also, such a class may not be trivial even over domains "morally" equivalent to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ - for instance, the ring $\mathbb{Z}^{17}$ yields the same computability theory (in an appropriate sense), but the class I describe above is nontrivial for this structure.

Comment: I have that book. This doesn't answer my question, which is specifically about complexity classes **not** motivated by ones already considered in classical complexity theory (such as $P$ and $NP$).

Comment: You may want to check algebraic complexity and arithmetic circuit literature though I don't know if this particular measure has been studied.